# mysql multiple tables vs json type

Tags: mysql, json

I have multiple tables:

```
results
id, data

filters
id, name, table

filter_strings
id, filter_id, result_id, value

filter_integers
id, filter_id, result_id, value

filter_booleans
id, filter_id, result_id, value
```

I use this structure because I do not know the filters in advance and therefore I cannot have a table with predefined filters columns like this:

```
results
id, data, filterA, filterB, ...
```

However I could also use the json type to store all filter data within that:

```
results
id, data, filters
1, 'somedata', { age: 30, gender: 'male' }
```

This would reduce the complexity of my DB quite a bit, but I am afraid that queries will take a big performance hit. Does someone have experience with JSON queries?

Comment: Your table structure looks strange. Can you explain why it is how it is?

Comment: If you use JSON, will you be using the json query functions of MySQL? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html
If you are, I would expect the queries to be fairly rapid with MySQL having developed JSON parsing.

Comment: You can have index on generated columns. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html).

Comment: @juergend The filters are defined by users, So I do not know what they will be. This is the only option I could find that allows to have custom filters with different data types.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from what kind of SELECT will you do on your db. If your query will be almost on the filters content it could be better to have a query directly on the tables rather than have to get all of the rows and then parse the JSON.
I used mainly MySQL DB that does not supports a direct parsing on JSON, but I've heard that latest versions of Postgress seems to support it, in that case it could be a good alternative.